# componentise single page JSP without controller

Tags: jsp

I don't have the use of controller and inherited a large JSP with a lot of winding scriptlets. After user signs on with a SAML token and a role is determined uses scriptlets to work at what is displayed in the same JSP.

The task I have been given is :-

1. Reduce scriptlets to minumum or zero if possible
2. Split this Main.JSP into 2/3 JSPs.

   - A.jsp will be reached if user has role1 privilege.
   - B.jsp will be reached if user has role2 privelege.

I just want a proof of concept if someone can help me as I a little JSP knowledge.
The remit is I can use Beans, JQuery & JSTL.
If you are able to give pointers/template so I avoid pitfalls would be great.
example code would be great `<jsp:forward page="a.jsp"></jsp:forward>`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="com.kax.common.*, java.util.* "%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Landing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%! String role = FakeRole.getAdminRole() ;%>
    <% if (role == "Role1"){%>
        <div>
            Hello Admin form
            <br/>
            <a onclick="doSomethingAdmin()" href="#">ClickAdmin!</a>
        </div>
    <%}%>
    <% if (role == "Role2"){%>
        <div>
            Hello User form
            <br/>
            <%-- I khow this bad --%>
            <a onclick="doSomethingUser()" href="#">Click!</a>

        </div>
    <%}%>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.
Jemrug

Comment: Share some code so that we can understand what is structure of your jsp.

Comment: You can wrap up functionality in custom JSP tags. I don't understand why you can't create a "controller" or servlet or anything.

Comment: My boss is insistent, I have to do it without a controller. So how would I do it using tags @Dave Newton. I was going to simply just use <jsp:foward> etc I am newbee with JSPs. Thanks for your help in advance. Some code examples would be great.

Comment: Search the web for custom Jsp tags. You can write them in jsp or Java. Your boss is wrong unless there a technical reason.

Comment: He does not want to apply MVC pattern and keep it very simple. He wants everything in the view(JSP) and get rid of scriptlets. Thanks I will see if I can get a handle on custom tags. Will custom tags be able to handle JQuery and possible SQL calls to the database? He dont want any frameworks involved either. So one thing at a time.

Comment: It's a terrible idea that *adds* complexity.

Comment: @DaveNewton why is my idea of :- If (Role1) foward to AdminRole.jsp etc?

Comment: I don't know what you were trying to say there. In any case: putting complex logic in views conflates to completely separate concerns. Adding a servlet to do the work you're doing in Java is the *least* you can do to alleviate this. It doesn't add complexity: it is standard practice that isolates units of work ("functionality"). Ideally servlets should *also* be simple, handling only the conversion of the web layer to the business layer. By making each unit focus on a single responsibility the code becomes much easier to reason about. This is Code Organization 101.

Comment: Guys I am so lost with tags. Do I extend SimpleTagSupport or TagSupport? I agree with you @Dave Newton , I can put all my business logic in tag handler. But have not a clue how to do it. Someone help me with writing this using custom tags.